# EAV vs Serialized Object vs SQL with Xpath?

Tags: sql, database-design, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement a badge system, the badge are based on user's metadata which are subject to change.

Those metadata are variable, and are set on the fly.

Example of metadata :

- `commentCount`
- `hasCompletedProfile`
- `isActiveMember`

etc. Later, I would want to add `hasGravatar` metadata, for this reason, I can't easily design and normalize a table.

Those data, while they are an important part of the application are not 'sensible', almost all those metadata could be re-computed that means that the integrity of the data is not part of constraints.

Currently, I know three options, even if I didn't know any of them.

- EAV
- Serialized Objects
- XML Field (I read somewhere that it is possible to store XML in a column, and use XPATH or something to query data)

All of these options look to have pro & cons but since I've never experimented with them, I don't really know which.

Do you have any feedbacks or advices?

I'm currently working with Zend Framework & Doctrine 2 with a MySQL server

Answer (score 2):

XML and Serialized Objects are both very similar as you would likely be using 1 column to store this arbitrary data. This quickly becomes very messy and difficult to easily distinguish in SQL WHERE clauses (though some DBMS have XPath support)

EAV on the otherhand will provide a separate row for every `Key => Value` pair you have, which you can easily extract out with a JOIN or subquery. The major downfall is that it can be a performance hit if you have a **lot** of data in here. Another drawback is that to keep things simple you would store all keys/values as text in the db. You could create an EAV table for every type, but it's not practically needed in most languages as what you fetch comes out as a string or can be converted there anyway. Simply storing user configuration/properties should be perfectly fine for EAV.

So you might have a table `user_metadata` with 3 fields:

```
metadata_id INTEGER
user_id INTEGER
key CHAR
value CHAR
```

You could then fetch this data all at once for a user:

```
SELECT * FROM user_metadata WHERE metadata_user_id = $user_id
```

Or you could fetch individual metadata along with your user data

```
SELECT user.*, meta_gravatar.value AS hasGravatar
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_metadata AS meta_gravatar
 ON meta_gravatar.user_id = user.user_id AND meta_gravatar.key = 'hasGravatar'
WHERE user.user_id = $user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

EAV: It is complicated and slow. It is an example how not to use an SQL database. You cannot have an index on properties in EAV and you need some nontrivial logic to get the data from database into business logic objects. Also your SQL queries become difficult to optimize.

Serialized objects: Serialization often depends on language or platform. There is no way of having an index on some property or search anything, but it is a simple way to store data of undefined structure.

XML field: Use of a standardized representation is better than serialization. Also, there may be support for such data structures in you SQL server.

JSON field: The same as XML field, however, JSON supports primitive data types (int, bool, null) and it is faster and easier to parse and serialize than XML. Some SQL servers provide some support for it as well.

All the three ways of serialization share the same disadvantage: No indices on the properties. In most applications, it is acceptable because the data are not processed by the database anyway, so they are simply a blob for the application. The good thing is, that this blob does not complicate the database schema and operations.

There is one more way to implement such an EAV alternative: plain old SQL table. If a new property requires some change in the application code, then you can add the SQL column as well. If you have user interface and application logic to define properties at run-time, you can teach your application to use ALTER TABLE queries. Then you simply add or remove columns as you need. In the end, it will be much easier and more effective than implementing EAV, as long as you have a good query builder.